# BST Tree Error: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Node'

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a BST. My code in Python is as follows:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def get(self):
        return self.val

    def getleftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def getrightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def set(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def getChildren(self):
        children = []
        if self.leftChild != None:
            children.append(self.leftChild)
        if self.rightChild != None:
            children.append(self.rightChild)
        return children

class BST: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def setRoot(self, val):
        self.root = Node(val)

    def insert(self, val):
        if self.root == None:
            self.setRoot(val)
        else:
            self.insertNode(self.root, val)

    def insertNode(self, CurrentNode, val):
        if val <= CurrentNode.get(): 
            if CurrentNode.leftChild:
                self.insertNode(CurrentNode.leftChild, val)
            else:
                CurrentNode.leftChild = Node(val)
        elif val < CurrentNode.get():
            if CurrentNode.rightChild:
                self.insertNode(CurrentNode.rightChild, val)
            else:
                CurrentNode.rightChild = Node(val)

new_BST = BST()

root_node = Node(2)
new_BST.setRoot(root_node)

array = [4,5,2,1,6,3]

for element in array:
    new_BST.insert(element)
```

I keep on getting an TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Node'
on line 41 in the insertNode section and I am not sure why. I am calling .get() which is suppose to return an int, so I am not sure why the comparison will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type annotations make it much easier to find bugs like this:

```
from typing import List, Optional


class Node:
    def __init__(self, val: int):
        self.val = val
        self.leftChild: Optional['Node'] = None
        self.rightChild: Optional['Node'] = None

    def get(self) -> int:
        return self.val

    def getleftChild(self) -> Optional['Node']:
        return self.leftChild

    def getrightChild(self) -> Optional['Node']:
        return self.rightChild

    def set(self, val: int) -> None:
        self.val = val

    def getChildren(self) -> List['Node']:
        children: List['Node'] = []
        if self.leftChild is not None:
            children.append(self.leftChild)
        if self.rightChild is not None:
            children.append(self.rightChild)
        return children


class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root: Optional[Node] = None

    def setRoot(self, val: int) -> None:
        self.root = Node(val)

    def insert(self, val: int) -> None:
        if self.root is None:
            self.setRoot(val)
        else:
            self.insertNode(self.root, val)

    def insertNode(self, CurrentNode: Node, val: int) -> None:
        if val <= CurrentNode.get():
            if CurrentNode.leftChild:
                self.insertNode(CurrentNode.leftChild, val)
            else:
                CurrentNode.leftChild = Node(val)
        elif val < CurrentNode.get():
            if CurrentNode.rightChild:
                self.insertNode(CurrentNode.rightChild, val)
            else:
                CurrentNode.rightChild = Node(val)


new_BST = BST()

root_node = Node(2)
new_BST.setRoot(root_node)

array = [4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3]

for element in array:
    new_BST.insert(element)
```

When your code is annotated, you can use static type checkers like `mypy`, which shows an error here:

```
tree.py:57: error: Argument 1 to "setRoot" of "BST" has incompatible type "Node"; expected "int"
```

which indeed does seem to be the problem -- you're creating a `Node` whose `val` is a `Node` instead of an `int`.

You don't see the bug until later when `insertNode` tries to compare the two values, which might make it hard to debug at runtime.  If you declare up front that `setRoot` takes an `int` argument, though, then `mypy` will let you know about the mistake (and exactly where it is) even before you actually run the code.

More info on mypy and type checking here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: You should mention `mypy` earlier in the answer; type annotations alone do nothing.